# search string as integer from array

Tags: java

I have retrieve all the strings from file and place them in array through splitting method. i want to know how to search int from array which is of type String. here is the txt file and my code:

```
student id= : 12
name :  nokia

student id : 123
name : usb
```

my code:

```
 import java.io.BufferedReader;
import java.io.File;
import java.io.FileReader;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.List;
import java.util.Scanner;

    public class Read {

        @SuppressWarnings("resource")
        public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException {
            BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(new FileReader(new File("test.txt")));
            try {
         //       String line = br.readLine();
                String line = br.readLine();
                List<String> list = new ArrayList<String>();  
                while(line  != null)
                {

                //  list.add(line); // add lines in list
                    for (String token : line.split(":")) { // Splitting each line with ':'
                        if (!token.trim().equals("student name")) { // Adding token to list conditionally.
                            list.add(token);
                        }
                    }
                    line = br.readLine(); // read next line
                }

                String [] stringArr= list.toArray(new String[0]);
                list.add(stringArr[0]);
                String [] a = null;

                Scanner in ;  
                in = new Scanner(System.in);
                String b= in.next();
                for(int i=0; i<stringArr.length; i++){
                    if(stringArr[i]== b){
                        System.out.print(stringArr[i-1]);
                        System.out.println(stringArr[i]);
                        System.out.print(stringArr[i+1]);
                        System.out.println(stringArr[i+2]);
                        System.out.print(stringArr[i+3]);
                        System.out.print(stringArr[i+4]);
                        System.out.print(stringArr[i+5]);
                    }

            //  System.out.print(stringArr[2]);
                }

            } finally {
                br.close();
            }
        }
    }
```

This is not printing my requirement.
My requirement, it should print like this:

Enter ID: 1

output result is
Student ID:1
Name : nokia

Comment: create a `java.util.Map` (ID > name) or (ID > Student)

Comment: where should i iplement this??

Comment: Step1: read the file, Step2: parse it to populate a `Map`, step3: ask user for input ID, Step4: lookup in the `Map` (using `get()`) for the ID and output

Comment: i have just recently started java so i am feeling difficulty in understanding so many data types. any concept you can give??

Comment: you mean i shd place the strings from file in map rather array?

Comment: Something useful in the answers?

Comment: yes i understand. Sorry for late response.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Because you have 2 lines to read to map an ID to a name, I would recommend you to read 2 lines, call a split on each and store the second values in a `HashMap` like @Adeeb suggested. That could look like this:

```
BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(new FileReader(new File(
        "test.txt")));
String line = null, line2 = null;
HashMap<Integer, String> db = new HashMap<Integer, String>();
while ((line = br.readLine()) != null && !line.isEmpty()) {
    line2 = br.readLine();
    if (line2.isEmpty())
        continue;
    int id = Integer.parseInt(line.split(":")[1]);
    String name = line2.split(":")[1];
    db.put(id, name);
}
```

Now you can read in an `ID` and call `db.get(ID)` to retrieve the mapped name.

**[OFFTOPIC]**

```
for(int i=0; i<stringArr.length; i++) {
    System.out.print(stringArr[i-1]);
    ...
}
```

You loop through an array, but you try to access the index `-1`, when `i == 0`. Think about what would happen ;-)

Answer (score 0):

As @RC has implied in the comments, you are working with a (key,value) pair.
You are storing Strings but lookup should be done using integers.

The easiest data structure to use would be a HashMap.

```
HashMap<Integer, String> db = new HashMap<Integer,String>();
db.put(id,name); //inserting into db
db.get(id); //retrieve name using id
```

Hope that clears things up.